# Dropwizard Exception Mapping

Tags: java, exception, dropwizard

I have created two ExceptionMappers:

```
GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>
```

and

```
ValidationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<javax.validation.ValidationException>
```

The GenericExceptionMapper checks if the Exception is of a specific type and if it is some mapping will be done. In all other cases it will be mapped to a 500.

The ValdiationExceptionMapper will map to a 400 with a specific response.

Now i'm observing several strange things. If i omit the ValidationExceptionMapper the GenericExceptionMapper is not called. Furthermore if i cut of the database connection non of the ExceptionMappers will be triggered. In both cases the response is a 500 html format. What i actually want is that every exception should be catched by the mapper.

I'm using Dropwizard 1.0.5 with the setting `registerDefaultExceptionMappers: false`.

Comment: How do you register your `ExceptionMapper` ?

Comment: With these annotations: javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider and com.google.inject.Singleton.

Comment: From your question several things can go wrong. This looks like it may be an issue with jersey, guice or dropwizard or your integration with dropwizard and guice. Can you provide a reproducible example of what you are experiencing.

Comment: Have you try `environment.jersey().register(newYourCustomErrorsHandler());` ?

Comment: If i do it like this: environment.jersey().register(newYourCustomErrorsHandler());. And then a Bean Validation fails the ExceptionMapper is not executed. If i throw a NullPointerException then the ExceptionMapper is executed.

Comment: I actually found out that if the database connection is cut off and an exception is thrown within a method marked as com.google.inject.Provides this happens. The exception has to be thrown while trying to access the database in my case i'm calling datastore.ensureIndexes(); (Morphia).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think setting @Singleton is good idea for a Resource.

On the other hand: 
This is the correct way to customize the response given for a particular exception by implementing  **ExtendedExceptionMapper**:

```
environment.jersey().register(new ExtendedExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException>() {
@Override
public Response toResponse(WebApplicationException exception) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
}

@Override
public boolean isMappable(WebApplicationException e) {
    return Throwables.getRootCause(e).getClass() == MustacheNotFoundException.class;
}});
```

[Dropwizard docs, Templates errors section](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/stable/manual/views.html)